# Can we use hystrix to rollback during eventual consistency?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, hystrix

Can we use the fallback method to reverse the transaction? Are there any disadvantages of it? Or is it fine?

Comment: Probably not. It's a circuit breaker, not exception handler. If the circuit is open would you even want to start a transaction?

Comment: But we do write fallback methods using it.